# unsigned char to SetWindowTextA

Tags: c++, winapi

I trying to fetch and display the host mac id

```
HWND Ui_Item = GetDlgItem(Wwnd_Mess, IDC_MYMAC);
unsigned char MACData[6];
UUID uuid;

UuidCreateSequential( &uuid );          
for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++){        
    MACData[i - 2] = uuid.Data4[i];
}

char HostMAC[13] = {MACData[0], '-', MACData[1], '-', MACData[2], '-', MACData[3], '-', MACData[4], '-', MACData[5], '-', '\0'};
SetWindowTextA( Ui_Item, HostMAC);
```

but this looks to just be spitting out random chars?  Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: What output were you expecting? Remember that `char` means *one character*

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you are relying on a private implementation detail of UUID. A UUID does not always use a MAC as part of its data. And what if the computer has multiple network adapters installed and thus has multiple MACs? You might consider using `GetAdaptersInfo()` or `GetAdaptersAddresses()` instead to retrieve the actual details of the available network adapters, which includes their MACs. Then you can extract the MAC of the desired adapter.

Answer (score 1):

The MAC address is just 6 bytes of data. Your code attempts to interpret each byte as though it were an ANSI encoded character. The result you get is exactly what would be expected. You need to convert each byte to a hexadecimal representation.

For example:

```
char HostMAC[18];
sprintf(HostMAC, "%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X-%.2X", MACData[5], MACData[4], MACData[3], 
  MACData[2], MACData[1], MACData[0]);
```

I'm not sure whether or not I put the bytes in the right order, but I'm sure you know.